# How to use <= inside an XML element?

Tags: sql, xml

I have a config.xml file that contains a SQL query.  The query will end up getting read and performed in c#.  However, I need to know how to write the query contained inside the XML element.  The problem is that the query uses <= in a WHERE statement.  The '<' part of the query causes the XML to think it is supposed to esacpe the element, I think.  How can i include this basic select statement in the XML file?  I noticed > works fine.  Obviously, I could swap the order of the comparison, but I want to know how I can specifically include < please.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <Connections>
   <Connection>
      <Source>Data Source=XXX-XXX; Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=True</Source>
      <Query>Select * FROM Info WHERE EffectiveDate <= GETDATE() </Query>
   </Connection>
  </Connections>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) block. Then you wouldn't have to encode your query.

For example:

```
<Query><![CDATA[
Select * FROM Info WHERE EffectiveDate <= GETDATE()   
]]></Query>
```

Comment: this sounds like the best solution, but when i added <![CDATA[ at the beginning and ]] at the end of the query, i now receive the error:  Unexpected end of file while parsing CDATA has occurred.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You could encode the `<` character in the config file `&lt;` and decode it for use.